# GUWF and firewall malfunctioning?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, internet, ufw

I keep adding IP addresses to the built-in Linux Mint "firewall" program (which is "GUWF" relabeled "firewall") and it worked for a while ... but now it doesn't look like it is actually blocking anything anymore for reasons I cannot discern.  I have checked, my big rule set is set to "active" in "firewall" and I can check it with uwf on the command line (i.e. "sudo uwf status") which registers as "active" and has all the same rules ... but it is like it just stopped blocking anything.

To test I just freshly added in [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) primary IP address -- 151.101.117.140 -- set the firewall to deny both in and out signal, all protocols, and all ports, and log all. But I can freely go to reddit without issue. Using the IPvFoo extension I can show that [www.reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) isn't rerouting to a different IP as some sites will do when blocked, instead it is connecting directly to IP address -- 151.101.117.140 -- even as UFW status and GUFW rules list that exact IP is set to deny both in and out signal, all protocols, and all ports, and log all. There is no log either, the computer is just freely accessing that site and its like the firewall isn't even paying attention at all. Meanwhile, using the IPvFoo extension I can confirm Brave browser is actively sending and receiving data from -- 151.101.117.140 -- every time I click around reddit or refresh a reddit page.  See picture below, the terminal ufw status printout is on the left, the "Firewall" (i.e. gufw) printout is on top right, and the bottom right shows Brave browser with IPvFoo showing the connection.

[image: Active yet inactive firewall]

Odder still is that I put in every single rule via GUFW, but there are a number of rules I can't edit because GUFW claims those were put in via UFW and those are locked because UFW always gets priority over GUFW. So I deleted all the rules via UFW and put them all back in (manually) via GUFW and the next time I checked certain rules were locked and uneditable because "Immutable Rule You can't edit a rule added from ufw" How is that possible? It feels like GUFW (i.e. "Firewall") is malfunctioning horribly.
I am hoping I just have a reaaaaaaaaly stupid setting flipped somewhere, because this is most bizarre and concerning, especially as the firewall was working great until about a week or two ago and then ... seems to have just stopped completely for reasons I cannot fathom.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description: Linux Mint 21.2
Release: 21.2
Codename: victoria
```

**EDIT:**  using `sudo dmesg -w` and GUFW logging set to high it looks like UFW is somehow secretly set to "ALLOW" a lot of things ... maybe everything, but there are absolutely zero "ALLOW" rules in either the UFW status listing or in GUFW.  Are there hidden rules for UFW and GUFW?  Is there a way to see all the hidden rules for UFW and GUFW?

**EDIT2:** Some people on other forums don't like my reddit demo because reddit has like 9 IPs it can route through. True, so below here is a ping trace to exactly that reddit IP I blocked -- all ports, DENY IN, DENY OUT and is listed as such under ufw status:

```
$ ping 151.101.117.140
PING 151.101.117.140 (151.101.117.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=75.1 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=81.1 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=90.0 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=221 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=117 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=68.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=61.2 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=87.3 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=9 ttl=52 time=267 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=10 ttl=52 time=81.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=11 ttl=52 time=91.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=12 ttl=52 time=60.2 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=13 ttl=52 time=82.4 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=14 ttl=52 time=239 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=15 ttl=52 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=16 ttl=52 time=183 ms
```

**EDIT3:** Someone on another forum wanted me to demo the ufw behavior with a clean profile, so here is that test:

```
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
~$ sudo ufw deny from 151.101.117.140
Rule added
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        151.101.117.140           

~$ ping 151.101.117.140
PING 151.101.117.140 (151.101.117.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=51.3 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=95.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=147 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=240 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=50.9 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=46.0 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=9 ttl=52 time=79.0 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=10 ttl=52 time=44.3 ms
```

**EDIT4:** Same someone wanted me to show the other block option direction and combination in regard to the ping starting from a clean profile, so here is that:

```
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
~$ sudo ufw deny to 151.101.117.140
Rule added
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
151.101.117.140            DENY        Anywhere                  

~$ ping 151.101.117.140
PING 151.101.117.140 (151.101.117.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=91.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=99.3 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=141 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=50.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=74.6 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=118 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=216 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=49.5 ms
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping 151.101.117.140
~$ sudo ufw deny from 151.101.117.140
Rule added
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
151.101.117.140            DENY        Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   DENY        151.101.117.140           

~$ ping 151.101.117.140
PING 151.101.117.140 (151.101.117.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=245 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=180 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=288 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=210 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=74.5 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.117.140: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=82.7 ms
```